# How to change URL in case of 404 page in Magento

Tags: magento, content-management-system, http-status-code-404

When I enter not found URL then, I am redirecting to 404 page.

But I need to Url also should be changed to 404notfound page.

So in case if 404, My url should be www.mysite.com/404notfound.

Please suggest me.

I tried to create new 404 cms page and assign to noroute. but still URL does not change.

I also tried to change CMS 404 page route, but getting Magento error with error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by adding single line at the end of function in,
`cms/indexController/noRouteAction`

`$this->_redirect($pageId);`

Answer (score 0):

This should be handled at the `.htaccess` level with the following line:

`ErrorDocument 404 /404notfound`

Comment: Thanks for reply. it is not changing the URL. I have also cleared cache.